# Proving a polynomial with complex roots is uniformly continuous without derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

If E is a bounded set and $p(x)$ is a polynomial that has no real roots, explain why $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ is uniformly continuous on E

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{p(x)}$, a function $f(x)$ is said to be uniformly continuous on E if

$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$, such that $\forall x_0 \in E$, $\lvert x-x_0 \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x)-f(x_0) \rvert < \epsilon$

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for some constants a,b,c

We know that $p(x)$ has no real roots if $b^2-4ac<0$

So $\forall \epsilon>0 $, we need to find $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x_0 \in E$, $\lvert x-x_0 \rvert <\delta \implies \lvert \frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}-\frac{1}{ax_0^2+bx_0+c} \rvert < \epsilon$

$=\lvert \frac{(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)-(ax^2+bx+c)}{(ax^2+bx+c)(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)} \rvert= \lvert \frac{a(x^2-x_0^2)+b(x-x_0)}{(ax^2+bx+c)(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)} \rvert=\lvert \frac{[a(x-x_0)(x+x_0)]+b(x-x_0)}{(ax^2+bx+c)(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)} \rvert=\lvert \frac{(x-x_0)[a(x+x_0)+b]}{(ax^2+bx+c)(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)}\rvert=\lvert x-x_0 \rvert \lvert \frac{a(x+x_0)+b}{(ax^2+bx+c)(ax_0^2+bx_0+c)} \rvert $

We haven't went over derivatives yet so I can't use them

Comment: Since $p$ has no real roots, $\frac 1 p$ is continuous on closure of $E$ so it's uniformly continuous on closure of $E$.

Comment: What about $p(x)=x^2+1$ and $E=\{\,z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\,\}$? Or is $E$ supposed to be a subset of $\Bbb R$? (but then the claim also holds for unbounded $E$). -- Also, you seem to argue only for *quadratic* polynomials?

Comment: @A.S. can you expand on that thought? Is there a theorem supporting this?

Comment: @A.S. How do you know it's continuous on the closure?  What if a zero of $p$ is on the boundary?

Comment: @Gregory I understood $E$ to be a subset of real line. Otherwise it's not true as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim.** Let $p\in \Bbb R[X]$ be a polynomial and assume that $p(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Then $f(x):=\frac1{p(x)}$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

*Proof.* 
The case of constant $p$ is trivial, hence if we
write $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0$ with $a_n\ne 0$ we may assume $n>0$. Also, without loss of generality $a_n>0$.
Then for $x\ne 0$
$$p(x)=x^n\cdot\left(a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}+\ldots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right) $$
Let $h=\max\{|a_0|,|a_1|,\ldots,|a_{n-1}|\}$.
For sufficiently large $x$, say for $|x|>\max\left\{1,\frac{(n+1)h}{a_n}\right\}$, we have $$\left|\frac{a_{n-k}}{x^k}\right|\le\left|\frac{a_{n-k}}{x}\right|<\left|\frac{a_na_{n-k}}{(n+1)h}\right|\le \frac{a_n}{n+1}$$
and therefore $|p(x)|>|x^n|\cdot\left(a_n-n\cdot\frac{a_n}{n+1}\right)=\frac{a_n}{n+1}|x|^n\ge\frac{a_n}{n+1}|x|$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
As just sseen, we have $\left|\frac1{p(x)}\right|<\frac{n+1}{a_nx}<\frac\epsilon2$ for $|x|$ large enough, in fact for $|x|>C_\epsilon$ with $C_\epsilon=\max\left\{1,\frac{(n+1)h}{a_n},\frac{2(n+1)}{a_n\epsilon}\right\}$. As $x\mapsto \frac1{p(x)}$ is continuous on the compact interval $[-C_\epsilon-1,C_\epsilon+1]$ it is uniformly continuous there. Hence for some $\delta>0$ (wlog. $\delta<1$) we have that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y$ with $x,y\in[-C_\epsilon-1,C_\epsilon+1]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$. 
If we consider arbitrary $x,y\in\Bbb R$ with  $|x-y|<\delta$, then  both are in $[-C_\epsilon-1,C_\epsilon+1]$ or (as $\delta<1$) both are in $\Bbb R\setminus[-C_\epsilon,C_\epsilon]$; in both cases we find $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. $_\square$